# How can append response data?

Tags: jquery, laravel

In current code I am getting file name when I upload file. After uploading I explode the file name and the response I am getting is given below. My problem is how can get data in jQuery and append with html?

In jQuery alert response shows `" Localization,dummy "` How can append these two data seperately.

**Console: Response**

```
{"success":true,"exploded_filename":["Localization","dummy"],"id":"2"}
```

**Console: Json**

```
success              true
exploded_filename    ["Localization", "dummy"]
0                    "Localization"
1                    "dummy"
id                   "2"
```

**Jquery in Dropzone**

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
            autoProcessQueue: true,
            parallelUploads: 20,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            maxFilesize: 10,
            maxFiles: 20,
            init: function() {
                myDropzone = this; // closure
                // You might want to show the submit button only when
                // files are dropped here:
                this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                    myDropzone.removeFile(file);
                    if(responseText.success == true){
                        $(".createProcessEntriesFileUpload").show();
                        $("#my-dropzone").hide();
                        $("#filenameFormGroup").show();
                        $(".createProcessEntriesMessage").hide();
                        alert(responseText.exploded_filename);
                        $("#filename").append('<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default download" href="" data-file="">'+responseText.exploded_filename+'</a> <a href="" class="removeProcessEntryFile" style="color: #333; cursor: pointer;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Add file detail</button></a><br>');

                        /*setTimeout(function() {
                         location.href = '<?php echo url("/");?>/customers/list/process/<?php echo $id;?>/entries';
                         }, 3000);*/
                    };
                });
            }
        };
```

**Controller Page**

```
public function storeFile(ProcessEntriesRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $files                     = $request->file('file');
        foreach($files as $file){
            $orginalName           = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $split_file            = explode('.', $orginalName);
            $exploded_filename[]   = $split_file[0];
            $extension             = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename              = str_random(10);
            Storage::disk('local')->makeDirectory($request->entryID, 0777);
            Storage::disk('local')->put($request->entryID.'/'.$filename.'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
        }

        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'exploded_filename' => $exploded_filename, 'id' => $id]);
    }
```

Comment: Should be `responseText.exploded_filename[0]`

Comment: @rmondesilva If I am using " responseText.exploded_filename[0]"  result is getting " L ". Because response is "Localization,pdf".

Answer (score 0):

Use [join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

```
console.log(responseText.exploded_filename.join(','));
 $("#filename").append('<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default download" href="" data-file="">'+responseText.exploded_filename.join('.')+'</a> <a href="" class="removeProcessEntryFile" style="color: #333; cursor: pointer;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Add file detail</button></a><br>');
```

or 
Use a loop

```
var totalfiles = '<ul>';
$.each(responseText.exploded_filename,function(i,v){
   totalfiles+='<li><a class="btn btn-sm btn-default download" href="" data-file="">'+v+'</a></li>';
});
totalfiles+='</ul>'

 $("#filename").append(totalfiles+'<a href="" class="removeProcessEntryFile" style="color: #333; cursor: pointer;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Add file detail</button></a><br>');
```

Comment: I didn't get. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Rahul what exactly didn't you get?

Comment: Localization and pdf are two file name. I will place another file name for pdf in my question.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. Currently I am getting response is {"success":true,"exploded_filename":["Create a BOT","Localization"],"id":"2"}. Created a BOT and Localization are file name. When I print "responseText.exploded_filename" I am getting "Created a BOT,Localization". How can I extract and append each data seperately with HTML?.

Answer (score 0):

Madalin is right, you should use the `join` method. If you have the array `data = ['Localization', 'pdf']`, then a `data.join('.')` will return `'Localization.pdf'`. [See the doc here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp).

Comment: pdf is a file name. That is not an extension I have updated my question